# How to resize an image in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

as here to change the size? I can not find the right method

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = newImg.ImagePath;
```

Comment: What you posted is not jQuery, it's plain JavaScript. What do you have? An `<img>` tag? A DOM element of an image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `100px x 100px` image.

```
var img    = new Image();
img.src    = newImg.ImagePath;
img.width  = 100;
img.height = 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(img).width(width_in_pixels).height(height_in_pixels);
```

Instead of `$(img)` you can also use a `$('selector')`. If you want to create a new one, use this:

```
$('<img/>', {src: 'url to the image'}).width(width_in_pixels).height(height_in_pixels).appendTo('#someElement');
```